# swipe gestures calling method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm struggling to get this to work.
I have a SKSpriteNode class named playerNode which I want to move with swipe gestures. I'm trying to call for the swipe handle method from the view controller but I get no response.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "playerNode.h"

@implementation ViewController{
    playerNode *player;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];

    // swipe gestures
    self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:player action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:player action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];

}
```

playerNode.h

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface playerNode : SKSpriteNode

-(void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender;

@end
```

playerNode.m

```
#import "playerNode.h"

@implementation playerNode

-(void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"swipe");
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        NSLog(@"left");
    }


    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"rigth");
    }
}


@end
```

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Add your swipe gestures into your SKScene:

Comment: I add them to the -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size method in MyScene.m  and still I have no response to the gestures. Should I add in a different method ?

Comment: Add the gestures to - (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *) view and target self

Comment: didMoveToView is more or less viewDidLoad in with SpriteKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your swipe gestures into your SKScene.

```
- (void)didMoveToView: (SKView *)
{
    self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    [self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
    [self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
}
```

didMoveToView is more or less viewDidLoad in SpriteKit

Then handle the swipes in the SKScene subclass

Comment: It works now, much better than place it in the viewcontroller class. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

In .h file, make player to visible to all

```
@property (strong) playerNode *player;
```

In .m file, set player as target..

```
self.leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.player action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];
```

**Note:** Before adding target, `playerNode` should created already.